# Border for UI feedback using binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

.NET/C#/WPF noob here. I'm trying to give a textbox a border based on a variable I can bind to (variable stores results of validation). My first attempt looked like this:

```
<Border ... Visibility="{Binding ServerName.IsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
    <TextBox ... />
</Border>
```

But this had the undesired side effect of hiding the textbox within it when visibility was hidden. After that I looked at DataTriggers, but it didn't seem like what I needed. Any ideas on how I can bind the border to that variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can layer it:

```
<Grid>
    <Border ... /> <!-- Bind as before -->
    <TextBox Margin="5"/> <!-- Margin to not completely hide border below -->
</Grid>
```

(You can also overlay the border by switching the order if that is preferable)

---

You could use a `DataTrigger` as well but you would need to change the appearance rather than hiding it completely.